# Recharts set Y-axis range

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Can't figure out how to set the range of Y-axis using http://recharts.org/

Want the Y-axis to display 100 in it's range instead of current 60.

[image: Recharts]

*Belive code example is not needed or fill purpose in this specific case*

Answer (score 132, accepted):

On  **YAxis** component set the domain value from 0 to 100(or whatever u want)

```
 <YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 20000]}/>
```

Check this fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/nhr9apd3/)

> **Domain** 
>   DEFAULT: [0, 'auto']
>
> Specify the domain of axis when the axis is a number axis. The length
>   of domain should be 2, and we will
>   validate the values in domain. And each element in the array can be a
>   number, 'auto', 'dataMin', 'dataMax', a string like 'dataMin - 20',
>   'dataMax + 100', or a function that accepts a single argument and
>   returns a number. If any element of domain is set to be 'auto',
>   comprehensible scale ticks will be calculated, and the final domain of
>   axis is generated by the ticks.

**FORMAT:**

```
<YAxis type="number" domain={['dataMin', 'dataMax']} />
<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 'dataMax']} />
<YAxis type="number" domain={['auto', 'auto']} />
<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 'dataMax + 1000']} />
<YAxis type="number" domain={['dataMin - 100', 'dataMax + 100']} />
<YAxis type="number" domain={[dataMin => (0 - Math.abs(dataMin)), dataMax => (dataMax * 2)]} />
```

Comment: That worked out perfectly. It was the "domain" name that confused me when reading the documentation. 

Thank you for a great answer 

Comment: What to do if i want interval should be in difference  on 100

Comment: The quoted text was really helpful. It helped me solve me related issue

Answer (score 21):

If the values of the chart exceed the customized domain range, then the domain boundaries set get ignored. I've had this problem because I use custom shapes, where negative values get stacked like positive values on top (but in a different color). Specifying the `domain={[0, 'dataMax + 1000']}` did not work, as the y axis still showed negative numbers – untill i set `allowDataOverflow={true}`

```
<YAxis domain={[0, 'dataMax + 1000']} allowDataOverflow={true} />
```

Answer (score 4):

if issue is still there it might be because of axis values is string types.

manually typecast your values to number it might get resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

One more thing about this

"type" can be of 2 types 'number', 'category'

domain will be applied for only number type of axis.

***if domain is not getting applied then check your axis type***

Comment: Don't use a string when you want a number!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are drawing a multiline graph and have custom YAxis on calculation.

So, You can define custom dataKey out of data then

```
   <YAxis type="number" 
           dataKey={(v)=>parseInt(v.someValue)}
           domain={[0, 'dataMax+100']} />
```

Answer (score 1):

After much experimenting, I wrote custom code to calculate the YAxis maximum value as follows:

```
const [yAxisMax, setYAxisMax] = useState(100);

.....
// json fetch here, and stored in 'data'
let currentMonthMax = Math.max(...data.map((o) => o.CurrentMonth)); // if the array has a custom object that contains 'CurrentMonth'
setYAxisMax(max * 1.1); // increase yaxis by 1.1%

.....

<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, yAxisMax]} />
```